# Get URL query string from rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I was given a application source code which has the following in .htaccess file. I was told to use PHP to get the Query strings.

```
E.g.
www.example.com/test-1
www.example.com/test-1/test-2
www.example.com/test-1/test-2/test-3
```

Without modifying the .htaccess code How can I get `test-1` and etc from the URL?

**.htacess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Technically speaking there is no query string in that URL. Query strings are the parts after `?`.

Comment: @deceze oh okay thanks

Answer (score 3):

Is it helps you? here it will extract with '/'

```
$output = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$res = explode("/", $output);
print_r ($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents()` or something else to retrive your strings. Then use `parse_url()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php